ActivityCompat.requestPermissions automatically denies permission
Problem: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is not showing the Dialog to the user, instead the permissions are automatically denied. This happens to both ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.
I have tried the suggested solutions on stackoverflow and didn't succeed. So I decided to make a minimalist project following the recommendations, it only has a MainActivity that just asks for location permissions and shows a message "denied"/"granted".
When debugging I can see that onRequestPermissionsResult the response is -1 for both permissions(inside int[] grantResults), meaning the permissions were denied, however the dialog asking for permissions never pops up. This also happens if I clear all the app data and uninstall the app and re-install it again (just in case the user had pressed "don't ask me again" at some point). After doing this I check the configuration on the Android device, inside the application permissions I can see that Location is in the "Denied" category.
I'm testing on Android 11.
This is MainActivity.java:
package com.example.robotito_calibration;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
        }

        if (!permissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this,
                    permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[0]),
                    1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // Check if the permission was granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, you can proceed with your task
                Toast.makeText(this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Permission denied, show a message or take appropriate action
            }
        }
    }

}

This is my Manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.robotito_calibration">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Robotito_Calibration">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Robotito_Calibration.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.robotito_calibration"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}


@blackapps Done. That definitely was confusing. Thanks for the feedback!

First ask for COARSE location. And only when you have obtained that ask for FINE. One by one.

blackapps has made clear that they will not do what is needed to turn that comment into an answer or get the existing but deleted answer undeleted. I recommend that you create an answer post by copying the actual solution proposed in a comment into a new answer post of your own. Consider fleshing it out according to [answer]. Do not forget to credit blackapps as author. It would be a pity if a workable (and your favorite) answer is hidden in a comment and risks being deleted.
